# MySQL query (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got the following query I execute using PDO.

```
$dbFindComment = $objDb->prepare("SELECT idPlate,tüv FROM car WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) >= tüv");

$dbFindComment->execute();

$usr =       $dbFindComment->fetchAll();
```

Executing the query in phpmyadmin results in a failure, in PHP I don't get any result because of this. I think it's because of the "ü" character. But there is no way to change colum name (customer project). Any way to get this solved? I tried using "`" mark around "tüv", but doesn't help.

Comment: What does "failure" mean? Any error messages? Have you *checked* for errors?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you must setting the connection character set to UTF-8

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
?>
```